# User Control Custom Struct Property lose value when build

Tags: c#, struct, visual-studio-2015, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

The Corner property shows up correct in the properties list, the property is not actually being changed in the Form1.Designer.cs file. Below is the code that defines the property:

```
private Corner _corner = new Corner(true, true, true, true);

    [Description("Which corners should be rounded"), Category("Look"), Browsable(true)]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Corner),"True,True,True,False")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public Corner Corners {
        get { return _corner; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _corner) return;
            _corner = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

And here is the code that my Form1.Designer.cs file is creating in the InitializeComponent method:

```
            // 
        this.flatButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(302, 270);
        this.flatButton1.Name = "flatButton1";
        this.flatButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 46);
        this.flatButton1.TabIndex = 5;
        this.flatButton1.Text = "flatButton1";
        //
```

Comment: Use `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` if the problem didn't solve, share the code for `Corner` struct and also it's type converter.

Comment: Now it is visible in Designer but is incorrectly initialized
`code this.flatButton1.Corners.LeftBottom = false; `

This my code:
[link](http://text-share.com/view/2f38be33)
[link](http://text-share.com/view/1d6d9c09)

Comment: If it's serializing all properties, it's working well. You can make it better by adding instance descriptor support to the converter. You didn't shared the converter.

Comment: I gave in the second link 
[link](http://text-share.com/view/1d6d9c09)

Comment: Code generation for property 'Corners' failed.  Error was: 'Specified cast is not valid.